# Ruby on Rails rescuing from 'Errno::ENOENT'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to rescue from 'Errno::ENOENT' in a Ruby on Rails 3.0.4 application. I currently have  controller with the following code:

```
begin
  `lame #{parameters}`
rescue Errno::ENOENT
  logger.info "command 'lame' not found: ensure LAME is installed"
end
```

However, the log code is never called, but the logs show:

> script/rails: No such file or directory - lame ...

If I create a ruby script with same snippet, the exception is rescued.

Comment: Are you sure `lame` isn't getting called anywhere else?

Comment: @Andrew LAME is not installed on the system and I created a generated a sample Rails application with a single action containing only this code. I'm reasonably sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby 1.8, `Errno::ENOENT` is not raised by shell execution / back-ticks - the error you're seeing is standard error, printed by the shell. If you want to detect this, I'd recommend looking for an exit code of 127:

```
`lame #{parameters} 2>&1`
if $?.exitstatus == 127
  logger.info "command 'lame' not found: ensure LAME is installed"
end
```

However, this will raise `Errno::ENOENT` in Ruby 1.9.

You might consider checking the output from `which lame` instead:

```
lame_installed = system("which lame >/dev/null")
# or even better
lame_available = !(lame_path = `which lame`.strip).empty? && File.executable?(lame_path)
```

---

Further reading:

- http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/exitcodes.html

Comment: Are you sure? If I run from irb `lame` I get "Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - lame".

Comment: It looks like the behavior has changed somewhere in 1.9.x. You should not have a problem rescuing this as an exception in Ruby 1.9.2-p136, but it will not work in Ruby 1.8.

Comment: I'm running Ruby 1.9.2 so it is very strange it doesn't work within my Rails applications. Thanks for the response! I added a check for the exit code immediately after execution then manually raise 'Errno::ENOENT'.

Comment: Yea, it's weird. There may be something Rails does to change the behavior, but if so, I don't know what it is.